# IDEA JAVAFX Project can't use library which has been imported with maven

Tags: java, maven

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8o1P.png)

Just like what the picture shows, I've already add dependency in "pom.xml".
And just like expected, "External Library" shows the jar I've imported.
But the truth is that, I can't use them!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The code as shown on your screenshot does not compile either way, you need to

- use the class with valid Syntax such as `Player p;`
- import it using `import javazoom.jl.player.Player;`